# python string characters to key and value?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm doing something wrong here, but not sure what.  I would like to be able to iterate through the characters of a string, see if the characters match a key in a dictionary and if so return the corresponding value.

```
string = 'happy'

dictionary = {
  "A":"10","B":"20","C":"30","D":"40","E":"50","F":"60","G":"70","H":"80","I":"90","J":"100","K":"110",
  "L":"120","M":"130","N":"140","O":"150","P":"160","Q":"170","R":"180","S":"190","T":"200","U":"210","V":"220",
  "W":"230","X":"240","Y":"250","Z":"260"}

for character in string: 
  print (character)
  for key in dictionary.keys():
    if str(key) == str(character):
      print (value)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to normalise the string you're iterating over. All of the dictionary keys are uppercase so:

```
string = 'happy'

dictionary = {
  "A":"10","B":"20","C":"30","D":"40","E":"50","F":"60","G":"70","H":"80","I":"90","J":"100","K":"110",
  "L":"120","M":"130","N":"140","O":"150","P":"160","Q":"170","R":"180","S":"190","T":"200","U":"210","V":"220",
  "W":"230","X":"240","Y":"250","Z":"260"}

for c in string.upper():
    if (v := dictionary.get(c)):
        print(v)
```

Or:

```
for c in string.upper():
    try:
        print(dictionary[c])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

**Output:**

```
80
10
160
160
250
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing lowercase chars with uppercase chars, and there is no `value` in scope. Instead you have to print the value for that given key in the dictionary.

```
string = 'happy'

dictionary = {
    "A":"10","B":"20","C":"30","D":"40","E":"50","F":"60","G":"70","H":"80","I":"90","J":"100","K":"110",
    "L":"120","M":"130","N":"140","O":"150","P":"160","Q":"170","R":"180","S":"190","T":"200","U":"210","V":"220",
    "W":"230","X":"240","Y":"250","Z":"260"}

for character in string.upper():
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        if key == character:
            print(dictionary[key])
```

Output

```
80
10
160
160
250
```